# Can I get a FILE* backed by data already in memory?

Tags: c, windows, file, io, fread

My code currently uses a library that I pass a FILE* to and it reads a bunch of complicated configuration data using the fread() CRT API.  I'd like to move the file to become an embedded resource within the file (a Windows DLL).  Unfortunately, reading a Windows resource gives me the data directly as a void*....which I can't pass to the library.

What I'd like is to be able to get a FILE* that is backed by a memory buffer instead of a file on disk.  Windows has CreateStreamOnHGlobal(), but that uses IStream* and I need a FILE*.  Unfortunately, I can't find any solution that exists for Windows.  **Is this possible?**

*The solution I could use would be to write the resource data into a temporary file, pass the temp file to the configuration parser, and then delete the file....but that is extremely inefficient and I'm dealing with a large amount of data.*

Comment: I think memory mapped files may give you what you are looking for. Checkout [Memory-mapped file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) at Wikipedia or [Memory-Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at MSDN.

Comment: I need the opposite of Memory-Mapped Files.  MMF let you treat a file like memory; what I need to do is to treat memory like a file.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I hope you can find the motivation to change your library to use a more suitable abstraction to take advantage of data in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you actually want is the equivalent of [`fmemopen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fmemopen) on Windows. No such equivalent exists.

You could use a named pipe as a workaround. You should be able to use `fopen()` to open the read end of a named pipe. The resource provider then passes the `FILE *` to the configuration parser while some other thread writes the resource data into the write end of the named pipe. This should be fine so long as the parser only wants to do sequential reads on the file (as opposed to seeking, which would not work on a pipe).

If you are willing to use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com), it provides [`fmemopen()`](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-api/compatibility.html#std-susv4).

Comment: Thanks.  That's a good suggestion.  Painful...but a good idea. :-)

Comment: I just thought up an even more gross hack. Append the data to the end of the DLL itself. Open the DLL as a regular file with `fopen()`, then seek the start of the data, and pass it to your library.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/tamatebako/fmem is a wrapper for different platform/version specific implementations of in-memory files

It tries in sequence the following implementations:

- open_memstream.
- fopencookie, with growing dynamic buffer.
- funopen, with growing dynamic buffer.
- WinAPI temporary memory-backed file.

  When no other mean is available, fmem falls back to tmpfile()